# Default file order of "dir" command in Windows console

Tags: windows, command-line, dir, ordering

Just wondering how Windows determines file ordering when running a `dir` command (without any arguments) in a command prompt.

I know you can explicitly specify an order, but just curious how ordering works when no parameters are used.

The reason is that I have a home stereo which can read songs from a USB drive, and it seems to play songs in the same order as that seen when I run a `dir` command on a windows XP command prompt. If I can figure out how the ordering works in a vanilla `dir` command, I might be able to control the play order of the songs on the stereo by changing certain attributes of the files

Comment: Which version of Windows? What filesystem on your USB drive. My `dir` lists in alphabetical order.

Comment: @David: Same for me in my Win7Home

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Windows XP. USB is FAT formatted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dir` (without arguments) command always shows files/dirs unsorted, in other words - in same order, as files/dirs are located on disk. NTFS file system "sorts" files/dirs internally (simplifying).

Thought, you may copy files one-by-one to achieve preferred sorting on your player.

Answer (score 5):

The order is "undefined", see below. But this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/230282) because there are a lot of tools made for your real sorting purpose

- [mp3DirSorter](http://funblog.themeparks.de/2009/03/sort-mp3-files-in-fat-folders-mp3dirsorter/)
- [YAFS: Yet Another FAT Sorter](http://www.luisrios.eti.br/public/en_us/projects/yafs/)
- [FAT Reader](http://public.bplaced.net/)
- [FAT-32 Sorter](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95721/FAT-32-Sorter)
- [FAT Sorter](http://fat-sorter.software.informer.com/)
- [Sort MP3 Files On MP3 Player](http://www.murraymoffatt.com/software-problem-0010.html)
- https://github.com/maxpat78/FATtools
- https://svnpenn.github.io/rosso/
- [How to reorder the files of a FAT32 file system?](https://superuser.com/q/376577/241386)

---

According to [Microsoft's `dir` documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20120210164348/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/dir.mspx?mfr=true) (emphasis mine)

> `/o [[:]SortOrder]`: Controls the order in which `dir` sorts and displays directory names and file names. **If you omit `/o`, `dir` displays the names in the order in which they occur in the directory**. If you use `/o` without specifying `SortOrder`, `dir` displays the names of the directories, sorted in alphabetic order, and then displays the names of files, sorted in alphabetic order. The colon (`:`) is optional.

The *order in which files occur in a directory* depends on the file system and how they store file lists in a directory entry:

- In [FAT12/16/32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) the file allocation table is just a simple **linear** list and when a new file is created it's simply put in an empty space in the list. Hence depending on the creation and deletion state the list order will vary. That explains why mp3 players often play in the order you copy files to the folder
- In [NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) directory entries are stored in a **B-tree structure**, so the result will be an *almost-sorted list*

More on [Raymond Chen's blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20190212233555/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603): [What order does the `DIR` command arrange files if no sort order is specified?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140304-00/?p=1603)

> If you don't specify a sort order, then the **`DIR` command lists the files in the order that the files are returned by the `Find­First­File` function**.
>
> Um, okay, but that just pushes the question to the next level: What order does `Find­First­File` return files?
>
> The order in which `Find­First­File` returns files in unspecified. **It is left to the file system driver to return the files in whatever order it finds most convenient.**

You can manually sort the files by moving them to another directory in the order you want

> If the storage medium is a FAT-formatted USB thumb drive, then the files will be enumerated in a complex order based on the order in which files are created and deleted and the lengths of their names. But the easy way out is simply to remove all the files from a directory then move file files into the directory in the order you want them enumerated. That way, the first available slot is the one at the end of the directory, so the file entry gets appended.

---

See also [In which order does command COPY copy files from source to destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44204762/995714):

> The commands `COPY`, `DEL`, `DIR`, `FOR`, etc. do not sort file names matching a wildcard pattern before processing. `DIR` has option `/O` to request an ordered output depending on next character.