# How do I get my car stereo to see the music on the USB drive in alphabetical order?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, usb-flash-drive

I tried using a tool called Attribute Change the dates to be all the same, but it had no effect.

Comment: See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1319538/432690) *and* the comments under it.

Comment: Is the solution to defrag the usb drive? If so, I see that [defragging a solid state drive](https://askleo.com/should-i-defragment-my-ssd-or-usb-flash-drives/) is not good for it.

Comment: This tool does the job: http://funblog.themeparks.de/tag/mp3dirsorter/?frommp3dirsorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tool, frommp3dirsorter, does the job:
 http://funblog.themeparks.de/tag/mp3dirsorter/?frommp3dirsorter